# URL session is not maintaining in android

Tags: android, session, url

I am working on Android project and we are using session to check whether user is logged in or not. For that we have url as below.

```
 http://www.mywebservice.com/app/app.asmx/isUserLogged
```

When we login, session on the server have userId. Using above what we are trying to check is the current session have userId or not, however always it says User is not logged in.

Below is the code we used

```
private void IsUserLogged(){
    mloading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    GlobalFunctions.DisableLayout(mainLayout);
    Log.d("ExecuteBidAuction", act.getString(R.string.IsUserLogged));
    StringRequest login = new StringRequest(
            act.getString(R.string.IsUserLogged),
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response != null) {
                        Log.e("response IsUserLogged",""+response.replace("\"",""));
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    mloading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    GlobalFunctions.EnableLayout(mainLayout);
                    if (volleyError.networkResponse != null) {
                        switch (volleyError.networkResponse.statusCode) {
                            case 200:
                                Toast.makeText(act, volleyError.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case 500:
                                Toast.makeText(act,
                                        "Sorry, Internal Server Error",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            case 404:
                                Toast.makeText(act, "Sorry, Not Found",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(act, "Check Network Connection",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }

    );
    login.setShouldCache(false);
    login.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10 * 1000, 2, 1.0f));
    login.setTag(TAG);
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(login, TAG);
}
```

Can someone point me why I always get response as not logged in? Even I call login webservice and then call isUserLogged, still it says user not logged in.

***Can someone point what I am doing wrong?***

*This is working perfect in iPhone*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can get the cookies from the first response .
- Then set cookies using `connection.setRequestProperty("cookie",cookie_value);`

I had the same issue & solved by setting cookie values . For me also , it was working fine in the iPhone Application .

Comment: can you post code for getting cooking from first response?